# Debugging Lua Garbage Collection

Tags: debugging, lua, garbage-collection

I have some objects in a large lua codebase (embedded in c++ codebase) that somehow never get garbage collected.

I suspect something is still holding a reference to these objects.

How can I debug this?

Is there a tool, Lua-side or C-side, that lets me print out all the references that are keeping an object alive?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703013/what-is-the-best-way-for-debug-output-for-the-lua-garbage-collector